# Detecting an Advancing Item in a List

Tags: list, algorithm

Let's say we have a list of items, these items change order constantly. Let's say we get an updated version of the list on a regular basis (one second, one minute or one week), with each update, the positions of items may change.

Through these updates, we notice an item that moves up in the list, or even a new item enters the list and moves up the ranks. The list has a fixed size, so a new item will dislodge a previously existing item. What is the best algorithm to detect and highlight the advancing item?

Comment: My first idea would be to convert the list into a map: item -> position.

Comment: So actually you are saying that in one interval, several or all elements can be moved or replaced. Sounds like pure chaos. What would you want to highlight when [1,2,3,4,5,6] goes to [3,9,6,1,5,8] in one interval?

Comment: @trincot in your example, we can see that 1 has really advanced (from left to right) through the list, so I really would like to pick it up and highlight it!

Comment: @Stef or item-> speed of change through updates! The higher the better, and going from right to left would give it a negative speed. I think this is what I want to achieve, but I'm really interested if there is already an already known algorithm to solve such a problem, or should I write it myself!

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem you encounter when tracking numbers that have moved to a greater index?

Comment: Imagine a derby with horses, and you want to highlight the horse that is advancing really good through the derby!

Comment: I imagine it, but I don't see the problem. What is the problem you have with implementing this?

Comment: @trincot as I wrote to Stef, I want to know if there is already an algorithm to solve such a problem.

Comment: Sure, for each element in the original array, locate it in the new array. If its location is greater than the original index, color it. That's one algorithm.

Comment: Otherwise, I think I can calculate the speed of change of position. Number of position changes / number of updates (let's say 3 or 5 updates), then the item with the highest speed would be highlighted .

Comment: If you have a problem implementing this, then focus your question on your attempt. But now it seems you are still contemplating on which item should be highlighted (speed? calculated over 3 updates?). You'd have to settle on that first. I will leave this discussion for now, as it seems this question needs some clarification, specification and a problem statement that relates to your attempt.